# Scalable QR decomposition algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Suppose one has a processor for QR decomposition of complex matrix of size *4 x 4*. So if it is necessary to decompose *M x M* complex matrix, *A*, one can represent it as *R x R* block matrix *[C<sub>ij</sub>]* (block size is *4 x 4* to match given processor dimension) and do *4 x 4* decomposition *N* times to achieve *A = QR*. The support operationes between steps are skiped for simplicity.

So the question is: how *N* depends on *R*?

My assumption was *N = R<sup>3</sup>*. This result is right for block matrix multiplication (according to Golub, Van Loan). The reason I think so QR and Multiplication are both level 3 algorithms, so complexity is of *O(N<sup>3</sup>)*.

Thanks.